# code ascii for '0' shifts from 48 to 0 how do i fix it?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a table containing the ASCII code for all numbers contained in the base 16 (they are characters), but the character '0' is not working as intended, in the  loop 'for' I can see that the code ASCII stays at 48 but once I exit it and I try to see the code ASCII for '0' once more, it has now moved to 0

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    if(i>9){
        tableaubase[i]=48+i+7;
    } else{
        tableaubase[i]=48+i;
    }
    printf("tableaubase[%d] : %d \n", i, tableaubase[i]);
    printf("tableaubase[%d] : %d \n", 0, tableaubase[0]);

}

printf("tableaubase[%d] : %d \n", 0, tableaubase[0]);
```

Comment: Don't hard-code ASCII codes, use character constants like `'0'` and `'a'`

Comment: What is the declaration of `tableaubase`?

Comment: Is it possible that tableaubase accidentally overlaps some other variable, perhaps you write out of bounds somewhere?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Barmar it is : char tableaubase[16];

Comment: The code snippet looks fine, and I can't reproduce the problem. The last line prints `tableaubase[0] : 48`

Comment: @Barmar meanwhile, I realised i had two declarations for the variable i, once in the loop 'for' and one outside of it and after removing it seems to be working fine, maybe that was the problem ?

Comment: You don't use `i` in the last `printf()`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the help, you've helped me solve the problem ^^

Comment: I don't see how. It sounds like the code with the problem isn't the same as what you posted.

Comment: The posted code is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want

```c
if (i < 10) {
    tableaubase[i] = '0' + i;
} else{
    tableaubase[i] = 'A' + (i-10);
}
```

Note that this expects an ASCII-based machine. Letters aren't consecutive on EBCDIC-based machines.

This won't change what happens for `i == 0`, which was already correct. This just makes the code more readable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ug, the most annoying type of error. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

```
char base16[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```